# handle gstreamer pop-up Window in WinForms from Gst.Parse.Launch

Tags: c#, winforms, gstreamer, glib, gstreamer-sharp

Hi does anybody know if it's possible to have gstreamer-sharp parse a pipeline binding string to a Gst.Pipeline object?

If the following line of code executes it pops up the stream in an internal Gstreamer Window.

```
Gst.Parse.Launch("videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink");
```

I am wondering if there is a way to get a Gst.Pipeline object from the Parse class so I can handle the gstreamer Window creation and redirect the output to a panel on my form?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Element returned from Gst.Parse.Launch should actually be a Gst.Pipeline

Comment: hi @Darkice thanks for your help on this!  Not sure what was going on but **Gst.Parse.Launch** doesn't seem to be acting consistently from what I have seen the past week.  Usually it brings up an external video in the gstreamer internal window, but not today.  Though admittedly I have started a new VS project from scratch.  Do you happen to know if the internal gstreamer window popping up has anything to do if your application not have a **GLib.MainLoop** executing in a .NET **Thread**?

Comment: Actually, it depends what autovideosink configures for you. If it decides to use d3dvideosink then you will probably get a external window, if it's something else you might not get a window at all.

Comment: You do not necessarily need a mainloop because the video system works independently. However, you will not be able to use the eventing system so error messages from the pipeline will not be posted.